# Can I use the same instance of EKEventStore on different threads?

Tags: ekeventstore

I was wondering if it is safe to use a single instance of `EKEventstore` on different threads?  I can't find anything about it anywhere.

I would be intending to get a unique `EKCalendar` instance on each thread.

Answer (score 2):

The descriptions of enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:usingBlock: and eventsMatchingPredicate: in the [EKEventStore reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/predicateForEventsWithStartDate%3aendDate%3acalendars%3a) imply that this is safe to do:

> This method is synchronous. For asynchronous behavior, run the method on another thread with dispatch_async or NSOperation.

I'm currently doing this in one of my apps and it appears to be working.

Comment: I've moved it all on to the same thread as I was having issues with the first time an app was run.  After permission for using the store was requested maybe about 1% of users wouldn't have the permission propagated to the other thread causing lots of issues in the app.